# How can I set Visual Studio 2015's OutDir property programatically, e.g. in a pre-build event, in a C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, pre-build-event

I need to set the "Output Path" field (which becomes $(OutDir)) of a VS 2015 C# project to a path that is elsewhere defined in an environment variable XX_OUT_DIR.

Setting the value of the textbox in the project properties build page to %XX_OUT_DIR%, or any permutation thereof, e.g. "%XX_OUT_DIR%", doesn't work - it just creates an "%XX_OUT_DIR%" directory when building, i.e. treating it as a string rather than resolving it to the text contained in the environment variable.

I know in pre-build events, these environment variables are correctly resolved to their value.

But, I cannot find a way to SET the value of OutDir as a pre-build event. I can only read it, which doesn't help me...

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! That is the opposite of what I am asking as far as I understand. To put it another way, I need to change the value returned by $(outdir).

Comment: Okay, changing $(OutDir) in a build event is not possible.  That would seriously mess up the dependency checking that both the IDE and MSBuild do before deciding what to build.  Using a post build event to copy files elsewhere is possible.

Comment: Ok, good to know then! The post-build solution is also not good in our case, for reasons that are irrelevant to this question... But I'll have to figure it out then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of $(OutDir) either from within by editing the `csproj` file and changing the value. You can create a special build configuration and use the `Condition` attribute to handle your special circumstances. The rest of the setting could remain the same.

```
<OutDir Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Special' ">C:\MyDir</OutDir>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Unless I've missed something, that still does not help with setting OutDir to a value taken from an environment variable? In your example, OutDir is still hardcoded to "C:\MyDir", which as you say I could indeed just have entered in the project manually, no?

Comment: You can reference environment variables from with the msbuild file just like any other variable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties

Comment: It seems then that OutDir is a special case? I had tried what you suggest, and tried now again to make sure. Setting <OutputPath>$(UV_OUT_DIR)</OutputPath> in the project file directly results in "Properties->Build->OutputPath" being set to just "C:\", even though typing echo %UV_OUT_DIR% into a command line resolves to the correct path, i.e. "C:\repos\OurSoftware\build\release-3.0"